# Spring Security BASIC auth - matching password hash

Tags: spring, security, hash, spring-security, basic-authentication

When doing BASIC authentication with Spring Security I want to match password hash and not password itself. For the sake of storing hash and not the password server-side.

I have the following code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AppConfig appConfig;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/v2/**")
                    .hasAuthority(MY_AUTHORITY).anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureSecurityManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
            new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder>()
                    .withUser(appConfig.getCredentials().getUserName())
                    .password(appConfig.getCredentials().getPassword())
                    .authorities(MY_AUTHORITY)
                    .and()
                    .configure(authManagerBuilder);
    }
}
```

I've found some examples with BCrypt, however they're dealing with hashing the password and not incorporating hash comparison into BASIC auth scheme.

Or am I getting this wrong all the way and client should send hash and not the password to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have an example: http://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-password-encoding-bcrypt-encoder

> Once the password encoder is defined, while comparing password coming from the request with the DB password, spring will by default consider password in the DB is bcrypt encoded.

Also I recommend you the following link: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64631/is-it-safe-to-send-clear-usernames-passwords-on-a-https-connection-to-authentica

Comment: I'm concerned not with sending, but with storing the password from BASIC auth.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you, when you specify a `PasswordEncoder` you are specifying how you want to store your passwords. So using a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` your passwords will be hashed and then saved.

Comment: Just added .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()) to configureSecurityManager(...) method and it works.